# GitLab CI runner: remote: You are not allowed to download code from this project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Inside of one of my runner's logs, when I try to replay it, I'm getting the following error,

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/users/repo/.git/
remote: You are not allowed to download code from this project.
fatal: unable to access 'https://acme.net/users/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is caused when the person (admin) that tried to execute the pipeline replay had insufficient access to the repository they replayed it on. This can happen when the for example the pipeline is private and they're not member, but an admin hits the replay button. The admin's replay does not have the ability to download from the cache. **This bug is reported as [issue 21700](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21700) upstream.**

For a temporary workaround, you may opt to make the repository public if possible. Then the admin can replay the job.